# How to open TSV file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
DataFrame.from_csv('C:\Users\~~\data.tsv', sep='\t')
```

Error that I get:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: `\U` is an escape sequence in Python `str` objects. Use a raw string literal: `r'C:\Users\~~\data.tsv'` to ignore escape sequences

Answer (score 0):

Check if this work for you.

```
import csv

with open('C:\Users\~~\data.tsv') as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(tsvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: No, now I get:
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax